# How to change the reply_to option in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

I am using rails 4.

In my config/initializers/devise.rb file I set the

`config.mailer_sender = 'noreply@test.com'`

Which is setting for `from` and `reply_to` address at the email.

But I want to use different email address for `from` and `reply_to`.

How can I do that.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Devise doesn't let you configure this without defining your own Mailer at the moment. But my quick and dirty way is adding this to the initializer:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_mailer) {
  Devise::Mailer.default reply_to: 'foo@bar.dev'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this by setting the mailer_sender in Devise to the email I wanted users to reply to (in config/initializers/devise.rb):

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = "reply-to@example.com"
end
```

And setting the base ActionMailer default from as the address I wanted emails to be sent from (in config/environment.rb):

```
ActionMailer::Base.default :from => "Name <from-email@example.com>"
```

Remember to restart your server before testing!

Version info:

- Devise: 4.2.0
- Rails: 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```rb
  Devise.setup do |config|
    Devise::Mailer.default reply_to: 'no-reply@xyz.com'
    Devise::Mailer.default from: 'registrations@xyz.com'
  ...
```